# Mantener datos al editar formulario personalizado de una lista de sharepoint

Tags: lista, sharepoint-online, powerapps

Personalice un formulario de una lista de SharePoint con PowerAPPS, en este he creado un ComboBox que trae la información de unas personas desde otra lista. El formulario guarda la información cuando creo un elemento, sin embargo, cuando voy a editar algún elemento, este comboBox no se actualiza (queda en blanco) y no me mantiene el registro que había guardado anteriormente agradezco su ayuda.